# MATLAB plotting a changing vector in a while loop

Tags: matlab

I'm interfacing MATLAB with an Arduino for a circuits engineering project. I want to poll the Arduino for the voltage it senses at a given sensor, add that voltage to a vector, and then plot it all inside the same while loop. I have the first two parts down, but I can't seem to figure out how to plot the voltage vector over and over as it gets longer. Is there a way to do this?

```
%{
Ventilation Rate Sensor v0.1

This program uses a thermistor connected to pin A0 and analyzes the 
difference in voltage drop in order to assess the user's ventilation rate. 
Designed for use with a voltage divider using a 2.2kOhm resistor and a
10kOhm (at 25C) thermistor in series. Note that this REQUIRES the Arduino
to have the code for MATLAB interface already installed. This is included
in the MATLAB Arduino software page at
<<http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/
32374-matlab-support-package-for-arduino-aka-arduinoio-package>>
%}

clc
clear
close all

ard = arduino('COM3');
voltage = [];
timer = datenum(clock+[0,0,0,0,0,30]);


while datenum(clock) < timer
    sensorValue = ard.analogRead(0);
    voltage = [voltage (sensorValue * (5/1023))];
    hold on;
    t = [1:1:length(voltage)];
    plot(t,voltage)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) after the `plot` line. That flushes the event queue and forces Matlab to do the plot.

Also, instead of doing a new plot each time you could update the plot's x and y data. Perhaps that may be save a little running time:

```
h = plot(NaN,NaN); %// dummy plot (for now). Get a handle to it
while [...]
    [...]
    set(h,'xdata',t,'ydata',voltage); %// update plot's x and y data
end
```

Comment: @SciurusDoomus Glad it helped. Also, see edited answer with another idea that might be useful

Comment: Interesting. I don't really need to cut runtime on this since the plotting is more of a testing mechanism than the actual data I want to output. However, I'm sure I'll need it in the future or to make this program available on really old systems. Thanks!